# How to build and run emesene on OS X using Git

Tags: python, git

Anyone knows how to build and run emesene - the chat client in Python - on OS X once you get the code from GitHub?
I have searched online and I cannot find a source that is working. I did find some documents on sidhosting website. But that did not work for me completely. Hence I need help here.

Thanks
Sumod

Comment: After trying for quite some time, I decided to go back to Python 2.6 from 2.7. Emesene works fine with Python 2.6 once you follow the instructions. I hope they support more versions out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `python setup.py install` in the emesene directory?